# Таблица на HTML

Tags: html

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Возможно сделать такую таблицу постедством HMTL и тега table?!

Comment: да, у нужных ячеек border:0

Answer (score 4):

Вариант с использованием colspan и rowspan.

```css
td {
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

td.empty {
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2"></td>
    <td colspan="3"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2"></td>
    <td class="empty"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="empty"></td>
    <td class="empty"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```